# How would I identify what processes are causing my diskspace to drop to 0 and how would I recover the lost space?

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I have Windows 10 Professional installed on a laptop with a 2.1 TB SSD drive. As soon as I turn the laptop on, diskspace drops.

- Most recently, I watched the available diskspace drop from 2.1 TB to 720 MB when the laptop is powered on.
- This happens if I am on the Internet or offline.

I am going to put together a small console app to log space in each folder over time to a csv file at 30 second intervals. I could not find an app that would let me see the disk space usage per minute for each folder. There are many that do snapshots. I would like a consistent measure.

This may not be a Windows or O365 issue - the space drain to too high.

Below is a list of items that I have and am trying. Would anyone have any additional recommendations or ideas on the cause?

**I have tried the following**

1.All options to apply updates have been postponed for several weeks. This is done in `Settings | Update & Security`.

2. Disable Office 365 synch.
3. I tried Cleanmgr but the this does not free anything (even when run as Administrator).
4. The Remove options under `System | Settings | Storage` also do not remove or recover any space.
5. Virus protection is up-to-date and reports no malware instances.
6. Disabled all Microsoft Store downloads in registry.
7. Disabled hibernation using PowerShell. This freed 3.5 GB but did not stop the loss of diskspace.
8. Checked all `TEMP` and hidden folders as administrator under Users. I am the only user on this laptop.
9. Ran `SFC /SCANNOW`. This reported no issues.
10. Have spent about 2 hours with Microsoft support. They have downloaded logs and are examining them for reasons that this might be happening. They did not determine the cause during the call.
11. Stripped startup processes to those executed when booting Windows 10 in Safe mode.

**Next steps**

- I could not find a disk analyzer that would record diskspace in each folder over time. I am going to put together a C# application to log drive space in each folder to a csv file over time. This app will automatically close when space gets low. The rate of loss is substantial, so this will not need to run for a long period of time (less than 3 hours).
- Check SSD drivers(?)

Comment: I suggest using a proper analyzer (like TreeSize Free), you can then find out which directories are growing. Unfortunately, narrowing it down may take quite a few days with the free version, because you’ll have to do the comparison manually, e.g. with screenshots.

Comment: Your question isn’t clear. Use screenshots to clarify your problem. Be sure you use a tool to visualize your disk usage if your question is about disk usage. Be sure you edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: Or WinDirStat, https://windirstat.net/

Comment: Also look elsewhere besides Windows and Office.  These do not and have not consumed 5GB daily.  Something else is using up your space .  I also use Tree Size .  Good App

Comment: For this sort of thing.. I use an old program from the 90s called "Scanner". It can be found [here](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/).  What makes this one different is the WAY it shows you the data making it easy to find things sitting deep in a tree.  I also use the suggestions above depending on what it is that I am looking for.

Comment: Maybe WizTree can help you find it?

Answer (score 2):

You may verify the disk-space used by folders using any of the
programs suggested in the comments above.
This answer is for the case where this advice doesn't find anything.

When the disk space is taken up by a temporary file that was
never closed or flushed to the disk, the file itself will have
zero-size in the file-table, but will nevertheless be
taking up space.
If the file is temporary, it will be deleted when closed by
its program, so even then leaving no trace behind.

To find such a file is extremely difficult, but here are a couple of ideas:

- Look in the folders that are used for temporary files and look for
  a file (perhaps zero-sized) that is the first when sorting by date
  in descending order, or that keeps on actively returning to the
  first position.
  To find these folders, look in the Start menu for
  "Edit the system environment variables" and
  "Edit environment variables for your account".
- Install
  [Everything by voidtools](https://www.voidtools.com/),
  specify the disks to index and give it time to index everything,
  then display all your files in descending order of Date Modified.
  Look for an active file that keeps on returning to the
  first position.

If you're lucky enough to identify the file(s) that is(are)
being written, you can find the owning process by querying
for the file-name using
[Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer).

These are methods that I have used to locate such misbehaved
programs, but they only work for programs with an orderly and
logical behavior.

Comment: Why downvote this answer ???

Comment: No idea why the downvote. I voted you back up. I noticed the question when I was at work a few hours ago and wanted to post my own answer in the same vein. By the time I got home you had already beaten me to it.

Comment: @Tonny: Thanks, and feel free to comment on anything I might have overlooked.